# how create a excel file with multiple sheets using ExcelPackage

Tags: excel, package

This source code:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile, template))
    {
      ExcelWorksheet worksheet = null;
      foreach (DataTable dt in dsExcel.Tables)
      {
        worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName);
        worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[dt.TableName];
        ExcelCell cell;
        const int startRow = 9;
        int row = startRow;
        int col = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
          foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
          {
            worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = dr[dc].ToString();
            col++;
          }
          col = 1;
          row++;
        }
      }
      xlPackage.Save();
    }
```

I am getting error at `xlpackage.save i.e. object reference not set to an instance.`

How to generate an excel file with multiplesheets using an excel template?

Comment: did you get final solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug, documented [here](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=7005).  Unfortunately, it looks like the fix is to edit the source code of ExcelPackage itself.